# Can't access to CloudKit dashboard and containter

Tags: containers, icloud

I have a problem with CloudKit containers. My team admin added one in Apple Developer but I still got a message in XCode:

> Add the iCloud containers entitlement to your App ID
>   You are not permitted to add App IDs to this team. Please contact one of Your admins, who can add the App ID on Your behalf.

The continer was added in Apple Developer but I still can't access Dashboard. The team admin should open my project and then try to add App ID via XCode logged in his developer account ?

Comment: Carefully compare the container IDs, I had a typo which took me now 2h to spot...

Comment: I'm still not able to access CKD, still no idea why. Did you solve it yet?

Answer (score 1):

please check your Provisioning Profiles. are already download it?
and please check this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

maybe it can help you

Comment: Not fully. If you are not a agent or admin, you will not be able to go through the whole processes managed by Xcode exclusively.